# How can i let python write all errors to a spesific logfile?

Tags: python

here is my code

```
import sys
import logging
import traceback
import MySQLdb

def log_except_hook(*exc_info):
        text = "".join(traceback.format_exception(*exc_info))
        logging.error("Unhandled exception: %s", text)

sys.excepthook = log_except_hook

db = MySQLdb.connect("sdfgdfgsdgd.nl","1","1","1" )
cursor = db.cursor()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup a logger which will write to a file. See the [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file) for an example on how to do this.